# What does "Deleting a record type also deletes the related path" mean?

Tags: record-type

in the Help
https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recordtype_considerations.htm&type=0
it says "Deleting a record type also deletes the related path."
What does that mean?

Comment: As per my understanding, recordtype has control over page layout and picklist values. However, all those page layouts and picklist values that are assigned to this record type will not binded anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a metadata type named 'pathAssistant' which is related to a specific Record Type. Deleting this Record Type would delete the associated pathAssistant. (the process graph you can see on opportunities)

Comment: It seems odd to make this a metadata field on RecordType if it is only for Opportunities. Maybe it will enable extensions to other sorts of paths for other objects in the future.

Comment: @ElHombre55 : It can be enabled on other objects already. :)